# oracle sql union order by

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, union

This is a certification question case A and case B, why it works in case B, but doesn't work in case A

```
case A (not working)
select col_a, col_b, 'b' from table_a
union
select col_a, col_b, 'a' from table_a
order by 'b';

case B (working)
select col_a, col_b, 'b' from table_a order by 'b';
```

Comment: What are you trying to do there? Please show some sample data of your table(s) and the expected result.

Comment: I learning for certificate with simple select  order by 'b' is working, but with union order by 'b' gives error, can't find any good explanation

Comment: `'b'` is a string literal. i.e. constant value. What do you want to order by?

Comment: this is a certification question case A and case B, why it works in case B, but doesn't work in case A

Comment: Neither query "works" in the sense that it orders the result rows, because you order by a string constant which is the same value for every row. The `ORDER BY` clauses make no sense hence. For some reason it results in an error in the `UNION` query. I don't now why this happens. I consider this a flaw in the DBMS. In my opinion, Oracle should either allow or forbid `ORDER BY <constant>` clauses and apply that rule to both queries. (Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/FXMZXCsg)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner See my answer but the column is not identified by the literal `'b'` but is identified by the quoted identifier `"'B'"` and when you use the correct identifier then it works and does order the rows by the priority [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EoUmWqJN).

Answer (score 2):

You're sorting data by a string literal, `'a'` which is as good as any other string literal, such as `'Littlefoot'`: both are useless, but are *allowed*:

```
SQL> select dname, 'a' from dept order by 'a';

DNAME          '
-------------- -
ACCOUNTING     a
RESEARCH       a
SALES          a
OPERATIONS     a

SQL> select dname, 'a' from dept order by 'Littlefoot';

DNAME          '
-------------- -
ACCOUNTING     a
RESEARCH       a
SALES          a
OPERATIONS     a

SQL>
```

`order by` clause - applied to `union`ed queries - works for the whole data set returned by that union:

```
SQL> select dname, 'a' from dept where deptno <= 20
  2  union
  3  select dname, 'b' from dept where deptno > 20
  4  order by dname;

DNAME          '
-------------- -
ACCOUNTING     a
OPERATIONS     b
RESEARCH       a
SALES          b

SQL>
```

As you already know, sorting by string literal won't work in this case:

```
SQL> select dname, 'a' from dept where deptno <= 20
  2  union
  3  select dname, 'b' from dept where deptno > 20
  4  order by 'Littlefoot';
order by 'Littlefoot'
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression


SQL>
```

That error literally means:

> You tried to execute a SELECT statement that included a ORDER BY clause that referenced a column number that did not correspond to a valid column in your SELECT list.

As you were already told, you could use an **alias** or column's **position**, or use that `union` as a **subquery** and then apply sorting by a string literal - in that case, it'll (again) work:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from (select dname, 'a' from dept where deptno <= 20
  3        union
  4        select dname, 'b' from dept where deptno > 20
  5       )
  6  order by 'Littlefoot';

DNAME          '
-------------- -
ACCOUNTING     a
OPERATIONS     b
RESEARCH       a
SALES          b

SQL>
```

That's useless (as it was before), but it is allowed.

One could *hope* that something like this would work ("hope" by means of implicit data conversion, where Oracle would convert `'2'` (a string) to `2` (a number) and sort by position), but - nope:

```
SQL> select dname, 'a' from dept where deptno <= 20
  2  union
  3  select dname, 'b' from dept where deptno > 20
  4  order by '2';
order by '2'
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression
```

Positional sorting works, of course:

```
SQL> select dname, 'a' from dept where deptno <= 20
  2  union
  3  select dname, 'b' from dept where deptno > 20
  4  order by 2;

DNAME          '
-------------- -
RESEARCH       a
ACCOUNTING     a
SALES          b
OPERATIONS     b

SQL>
```

Therefore, I *suspect* that it is the `union` that *causes problems*. Maybe it is about the fact that `UNION` returns `DISTINCT` data set, and - with it - `ORDER BY` clause can't refer columns that aren't part of the `SELECT` column list, literally.

Comment: "sorting by string literal won't work" while true is unhelpful. Instead, "sorting by the column's alias will work" and the column will be implicitly be given an alias (if you do not explicitly give it one) so it is possible for the OP to perform their sorting. They are just using the wrong identifier as `'b'` is not in the select list (just as `'2'` is not in the select list for your query).

Answer (score 1):

`'b'` is a string literal and not an identifier for the column (as the identifier for the column is the quoted identifier `"'B'"`).

You can either use the column number:

```sql
select col_a, col_b, 'b' from table_a union
select col_a, col_b, 'a' from table_a
order by 3;
```

or use a quoted identifier and convert the literal to upper-case:

```sql
select col_a, col_b, 'b' from table_a union
select col_a, col_b, 'a' from table_a
order by "'B'";
```

or give the column an alias and use that:

```sql
select col_a, col_b, 'b' AS b from table_a union
select col_a, col_b, 'a' from table_a
order by b;
```

See the [`SELECT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)

> #### Set Operators: UNION, UNION ALL, INTERSECT, MINUS
>
> [...]
>
> ##### order_by_clause
>
> Use the `ORDER BY` clause to order rows returned by the statement. Without an **order_by_clause**, no guarantee exists that the same query executed more than once will retrieve rows in the same order.
>
> [...]
>
> ***expr***
>
> *expr* orders rows based on their value for *expr*. The expression is based on columns in the select list or columns in the tables, views, or materialized views in the `FROM` clause.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Restrictions on the `ORDER BY` Clause
>
> The following restrictions apply to the `ORDER BY` clause:
>
> - If you have specified the `DISTINCT` operator in this statement, then this clause cannot refer to columns unless they appear in the select list.

You are using `UNION` (and not `UNION ALL`) which is implicitly applying the `DISTINCT` operator so the restriction applies that you "refer to columns unless they appear in the select list." The identifier for the column in the select list is the quoted identifier `"'B'"` and not the string literal `'b'` (and also not the string literal `'B'`) and you need to refer to it as that (or by the position in the select list or by an alias).

Note: Even without applying the additional restriction from the implicit `DISTINCT`, the base restriction for `UNION` queries is "The expression is based on columns in the select list or columns in the tables, views, or materialized views in the `FROM` clause" and the literal `'b'` is not a column in the select list or from an object of the `FROM` clause so it would be valid if you used `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks for cases, for me it's hard to find theory why its happen in oracle docs

Comment: @JonasBikus Added some relevant documentation.